# Laravel Routing based on Query Params

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Is there a possibility to create a routing based on query parameters? For example, an external system is calling the following route:

https://example.com/api?Action=GetOrders&Key=abf24b12c3b2a4e4b4dabbdd

Dependent on the value of `Action`, I would like to call different controller methods.

How can I do this while maintaining the functionality of the Service Container and Dependency Injection?

I tried like this, but it did not work:

```
Route::get('api?Action={Action}', function (Request $request, string $action) {
    dd($action);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you avoiding `api/{action}`?

Comment: I would love to use this - but its an extern system which calls webhooks and i am not able to change.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel doesn't handle query parameters (?) directly in its routes.

In route

```
Route::get('api', 'ApiController@handleAction');
```

Controller

```
public function handleAction(Request $request)
{
    $action = $request->query('Action');
    // rest of the code

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use laravel routing method use something like

```
Route::get('/action/{action}/key/{key}', function (Request $request, string $action, string $key) {
    return 'Action '.$action. 'Key '.$key;
});
```

You should use Controller that can simplify.

If you like to do with https://example.com/api?Action=GetOrders&Key=abf24b12c3b2a4e4b4dabbdd **use $_GET['action'] or $request->action;**

**In your Controller**